# I am trying to consume kafka message from kafkajs, but not able to read the message,

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafkajs

I am trying to consume kafka message from kafkajs, but not able to read the message, please can you let me know the issue. Any Idea how to resolve this?

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
    logLevel: logLevel.INFO,
    ssl: true,
    brokers: ['b-1.dev-datafabric.nmz564.c20.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9094',
        'b-2.dev-datafabric.nmz564.c20.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9094',
        'b-3.dev-datafabric.nmz564.c20.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9094'
    ],
    clientId: 'local-client'
})

const topic = 'aws.identity.users.0'
const consumer = kafka.consumer({
    groupId: 'test-group'
})
const consumedMessages = []

const run = async () => {
    await consumer.connect()
    await consumer.subscribe({
        topic,
        fromBeginning: true
    })
    await consumer.run({
        autoCommit: false,
        eachMessage: async ({
            topic,
            partition,
            message
        }) => {
            `not able to get inside this`
            consumedMessages.push(message);
            const prefix = `${topic}[${partition} | ${message.offset}] / ${message.timestamp}`
            console.log(`- ${prefix} ${message.key}#${message.value}`)

        },
    })
}
`how to make this code work`
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
    run().catch(e => console.error(`[example/consumer] ${e.message}`, e));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```

> {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-06-29T04:54:57.414Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Runner] Error when calling eachMessage","topic":"aws.identity.users.0","partition":7,"offset":"52","stack":"ReferenceError: consumedMessages is not defined\n    at Runner.eachMessage (C:\biport\testkafka\index.js:24:3)\n    at Runner.processEachMessage (C:\biport\testkafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\consumer\runner.js:191:20)\n    at onBatch (C:\biport\testkafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\consumer\runner.js:393:20)\n    at C:\biport\testkafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\consumer\runner.js:409:15\n    at retry (C:\biport\testkafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\retry\index.js:43:5)\n    at C:\biport\testkafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\retry\index.js:75:5\n    at new Promise ()\n    at Runner.retrier (C:\biport\testkafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\retry\index.js:72:10)\n    at Runner.handleBatch (C:\biport\testkafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\consumer\runner.js:407:17)\n    at handler (C:\biport\testkafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\consumer\runner.js:58:30)","error":{}}

Comment: `how to make this code work` is not a problem statement - what's wrong? what do you expect your code to do? What does it do instead? What errors do you see

Comment: Have updated the error stack trace, can you please help here.